# Is there a better (more efficient) way to find if a string can be formed from chars of another string?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary, stdmap

This is interesting because it's a possible interview question, so it would be good to know the most efficient algorithm for this problem. I came up with a solution (which contains elements of other people's solutions) that requires a `map<char, int>` to store letters from the first string as keys, and numbers of their occurrences as values. The algorithm then looks through each letter in the `container` string and checks if there's already an entry in the map. If so, decrement its value until it's zero and so on; until the `container` is finished (failure), or until the `map`is empty (success).

The complexity of this algorithm is O(n), O(n) being the worst-case scenario (failure).

Do you know a better way?

Here is the code that I've written, tested and commented:

```
// takes a word we need to find, and the container that might the letters for it
bool stringExists(string word, string container) {

    // success is initially false
    bool success = false;       

    // key = char representing a letter; value = int = number of occurrences within a word
    map<char, int> wordMap;     

    // loop through each letter in the word
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {

        char key = word.at(i); // save this letter as a "key" in a char

        if (wordMap.find(key) == wordMap.end())     // if letter doesn't exist in the map...
            wordMap.insert(make_pair(key, 1));      // add it to the map with initial value of 1

        else
            wordMap.at(key)++;                      // otherwise, increment its value

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < container.size() && !success; i++) {

        char key = container.at(i);

        // if found
        if (wordMap.find(key) != wordMap.end()) {

            if (wordMap.at(key) == 1) { // if this is the last occurrence of this key in map 

                wordMap.erase(key);     // remove this pair

                if (wordMap.empty())    // all the letters were found in the container!
                    success = true;     // this will stop the for loop from running

            }

            else                        // else, if there are more values of this key
                wordMap.at(key)--;      // decrement the count

        }
    }

    return success;
}
```

Comment: What about listing all possible permutations of your string using `std::next_permutation`?

Comment: For starters, the complexity seems off. Your code does O(n) map operations, but each of these takes O(log n) time, so the time complexity is O(n log n) instead. A hash table would improve the average time complexity, but not the worst case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not use `std::map`.  Usually it has `O(log N)` write, and `O(log N)` access. And malloc call on write.

For `char` you can use simple `int freq[256]` table (or `std::vector` if you are so inclined).

```
bool stringExists(const string& word, const string& cont) {
  int freq[CHAR_MAX-CHAR_MIN+1]={0};
  for (int c: cont) ++freq[c-CHAR_MIN];
  for (int c: word) if(--freq[c-CHAR_MIN]<0)  return false;
  return true;
}
```

Complexity of this code is `O(N + M)`, where `N` and `M` are: `word.size()` and `cont.size()`. And I would guess that it is at least 100 times faster even from small sized inputs.

Comment: What's the weird POSIX comment? Also, why the weird cast to `size_t` ? `(size_t)-1` is absolutely going to overflow `freq[256]`. At least `map<char, int>` will accept any char.

Comment: OP input type is `std::string` which has plain `char`. Good catch on overflow. Corrected.

Comment: freq[-1]  will now underflow. You really should use `freq[c-CHAR_MIN]` which works except in pathological cases, e.g. `sizeof(int)==1`, and you probably catch those by declaring `int freq[CHAR_MAX-CHAR_MIN+1]`.

Comment: Looks good but you actually have `word` and `cont` around the wrong way. (Look carefully at the OP's code: although he does things in this order, he's actually testing whether the `wordMap` is empty after every removal. Yes, this is more complicated than necessary.)

Comment: Your code looks good now, +1. But the OP's code is also correct I believe: `success` starts out as `false` and is set to `true` if and only if it should be.