# Optimal iteration though char string

Tags: c++, char, type-conversion

This derived from [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17991135/is-there-a-better-more-efficient-way-to-find-if-a-string-can-be-formed-from-ch/17991670#17991670). If we have:

```
const std::string& S = ...;
int freq[CHAR_MAX-CHAR_MIN+1]={0};
```

Are following four loops are equivalent? What do you like better?

```
for (int           c: S) ++freq[c-CHAR_MIN];  // (1)
for (char          c: S) ++freq[c-CHAR_MIN];  // (2)
for (unsigned      c: S) ++freq[c];           // (3) <-- BAD!
for (unsigned char c: S) ++freq[c];           // (4)
```

Comment: `for(auto&& c : S)` :)

Comment: @Rapptz: That's not making it generic. You still have `CHAR_MIN`.

Comment: I have taken the time to make the CHAR_MIN/MAX bit generic too http://stackoverflow.com/a/18016752/85371

Answer (score 3):

2 is the best option, because it clearly demonstrates what you intend to use each character for (quite simply: as a character). That meaning is lost in 1, 3, and 4. As Rapptz mentions, you could also use `for (auto c : S)` if you have a compiler that supports it (C++11 standard).

Also, there is no point storing a char in an  int (1), unsigned int (3), or unsigned char (4), since those can store values larger than char.

Comment: range-based for is a C++11 addition so it'd be weird if it supported it but not `auto`.

Comment: Also, `int` and friends can suffer unwanted sign extensions. However, you didn't mention/consider `std::wstring`

Comment: @sehe: Good point, thanks. I'm wondering if it is worth mentioning, though (OP is using a plain `std::string`)

Comment: unsigned char is better than char?

Comment: @Quonux what's the context? It's not supported by the standard specification for any kind of basic_ifstream e.g. So, no `char` is good if you're using `char`s. However, when passing to e.g. `std::is_space`, `std::to_lower` etc. make sure you doubly cast: `static_cast<int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))`

Comment: I've gave +1 yesterday (and it remains), but answer is incorrect. See my answer.

Comment: @sehe: The question links back to another question comparing `int[]` and `std::map<char, int>`. For std::wstring, I'd claim that `std::map<wchar_t, int>` would be more appropriate, and then tack on a huge warning about Unicode Normalization.

Comment: @MSalters one could equally well warn about codepages/character sets/ encodings with std::string (it could be EBCDIC, utf8, latin1...)

Answer (score 1):

Making this properly generic:

```
#include <limits>
#include <vector>

template <typename C, typename T = typename C::value_type>
  std::vector<unsigned> histogram(C const& container)
{
    std::vector<unsigned> result(std::numeric_limits<T>::max() - std::numeric_limits<T>::min());
    for(auto& el : container)
        result[el - std::numeric_limits<T>::min()]++;

    return result;
}
```

Now, this will result in unusefully large result vectors for large element type `T` (regardless of input length). Consider using a map:

```
// for very large char types, consider
#include <map>

template <typename C, typename T = typename C::value_type>
  std::map<T, unsigned> histogram_ex(C const& container)
{
    std::map<T, unsigned> result;

    for(auto& el : container)
        result[el]++;

    return result;
}
```

Some demonstrations of use:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     auto v = histogram   (std::string ("hello world"));
     auto m = histogram_ex(std::wstring(L"hello world"));

     std::wcout << L"Sum of frequencies: " << std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0) << "\n";

     for (auto p : m)
         std::wcout << L"'" << p.first << L"': " << p.second << L'\n';
}
```

Prints:

```
Sum of frequencies: 11
' ': 1
'd': 1
'e': 1
'h': 1
'l': 3
'o': 2
'r': 1
'w': 1
```

See it all **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f466ed1a5d0d5faade2438b6aa9ab56d-e223fd4a885a77b520bbfe69dda8fb91)**

Comment: +1, even though not exactly answer to "are these 4 loops equivalent?"

Comment: But: it's fully generic and doesn't require `<limits.h>` :/ (_the `map` approach doesn't even require `<limits>`_)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer myself and no correct answer from others so far, so I am answering my own question.

Loops are not equivalent. In (3), if `char` is signed and value is `-1`, it will be converted to `unsigned` with sign extension to value of `4294967295`.

As to **personal** preference of which loop is better, I prefer (4), because it does not have dependency on `<limits.h>`.

**EDIT**
(3) probably won't work correctly on non-two-complement systems. So (1) and (2) are better. There should be no performance overheard of converting `char` to `int` (or to `size_t`).

Comment: "In (3), if char is signed and value is -1" That is misleading; the char will never be negative because they are coming from a string! Hence my point about clearly indicating intentions, which only #2 does.

Comment: Why char from string can not be negative?  `string S="abc";  S[0]=-1;`.  Maybe this S have utf8 string.

Comment: Ok, sure, you can manually set a character to be negative. But presumably your program will operate on human readable strings, not corner cases. As for Unicode, you are correct that `char` wouldn't be suitable. But `unsigned int` isn't suitable either. Use an actual character type to make your intentions clear. You wouldn't store boolean variables in a `char`, so don't store `char`s in `unsigned int`s.